# как из url вырезать mail и токен на js без регулярки?

Tags: javascript

например в переменную mail="gogglepost@gmail.com" и token="$23y$113$px/m3Gi54234dgdfd2m1.edf43dgYnlqd2p"

url я знаю как выдрать а со строки значения нет(

http://localhost:3000/reset?email=gogglepost@gmail.com&token=$23y$113$px/m3Gi54234dgdfd2m1.edf43dgYnlqd2p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например с помощью етого : 
[`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)
[`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
var url_string = "http://localhost:3000/reset?email=gogglepost@gmail.com&token=$23y$113$px/m3Gi54234dgdfd2m1.edf43dgYnlqd2p"; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
console.log('Email', url.searchParams.get("email"));
console.log('Token', url.searchParams.get("token"));
```

Comment: спасибо большое, не знал о таком методе