# Как работать с get запросом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня в гет запросе, в адресной строке есть Условно запись ?age=1
Как ее получить объект с этой записью через js или jq

Comment: оно ? 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1005556/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-url-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-mail-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b0-js-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8/1005559#1005559

Answer (score 0):

`location.search` ? и все что после

`location.href` целиком

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, можно так (работает и в браузерах, и в Node.js):

```js
const params = new URL('https://example.org/?age=1').searchParams;
const age = parseInt(params.get('age'), 10);
```